# "Specified procedure could not be found" error while configuring Apache

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I try to configure Apache 2.4.2 for localhost so that it worked with PHP and PostgreSQL. I added following code to the end of httpd.conf file (updated after @Galadai's answer):

```
PHPIniDir "D:/Programy/php"

LoadFile "D:/Programy/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "D:/Gis/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/libpq.dll"

LoadModule php5_module "D:/Programy/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Trying to start Apache returns an error. When I run "Test Configuration", it shows following error message:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 519 of D:/Programy/Apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load D:/Programy/php/php5ts.dll into server: Specified procedure could not be found.
```

I had some path issues before, and the error message was almost the same, just there was "module" instead of "procedure". I have found quite a few hints for the "module" version, but their solution was usually to make sure whether the paths fit (I did this), both versions are 32/64 bit (both are 32 bit) and PHP is thread safe (it is). I didn't find any hint how to solve the "procedure" version of the error. I thought it might have been caused by difference in versions (I tried Apache 2.2 before), but this proved to be wrong.

EDIT: now I added PHPIniDir and the first LoadFile before the rest of the document ending, and only difference is that now the problem occurs on php5ts.dll too. The path is correct (if it wasn't there would be "module", not "procedure" problem - tested again).

Any other idea?

My PHP is 5.5.9 (thread safe) and PostgreSQL 9.3, my system is Windows XP 32 bit.

EDIT2: workaround through EnterpriseDB LAPP is not as good as I thought for the first time, so I'm still looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: Same problem : httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 514 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load D:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

According to [php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.setup.php)

httpd.conf should look like this:

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "c:/PHP/"
Loadfile "C:\php\php5ts.dll"
Loadfile "C:\php\libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "c:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. I guess apache needs some DLL to be loaded before actually loading the PHP DLL module.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. PHP module could not be loaded into my Apache installation.

I used a Windows x64 distribution of Apache 2.4.52 from https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx
and PHP version 8.1.2 x64, thread safe from https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.1

And after configuring php extension configuration inside ./conf/httpd.conf,
after running ./bin/httpd.exe, an error returned:
`Cannot load C:/Program Files/Applications/php_8_1_2_x64/php8apache2_4.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found.`

SOLUTION: Download a version of apache built with OpenSSL library, as PHP requires this one. LibreSSL won't work.

PHP module wants to internally call the functions of this module but the execution system cannot find the called function (procedure) and reports error.

Replacing bin directory in the Apache server folder with the folder containing correct binaries should work, but I don't know to what extent. Best would be to just set up a new installation and migrate configuration and data files.